# Return object from async method into CompletableFuture<Object> list?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, completable-future

I have a list of objects (from model class Name) that I want to process using an async method. The async method will take each Name object in the list and process it (check if it's not taken), I want to have a list of Names after they all get processed by the async method to get returned to the `isNameAvailable(LinkedHashSet<Name> nameList)` method

My executor config

```
@Configuration
@ManagedResource
public class ThreadConfig {
    @Bean(name = "nameAvailabilityExecutor")
    public Executor nameAvailabilityExecutor() {
        ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
        executor.setCorePoolSize(100);
        executor.setMaxPoolSize(1200);
        executor.setQueueCapacity(10000);
        executor.setThreadNamePrefix("nameAvailabilityExecutor-");
        executor.initialize();
        return executor;
    }
}
```

Service class which will call the Async method in another class

```
public LinkedHashSet<Name> isNameAvailable(LinkedHashSet<Name> nameList) {
    LinkedHashSet<Name> nameCheckedList = new LinkedHashSet<>();

    for (Name nameObj : nameList) {
        Name nameCheckedObj = domainAvailabilityServiceThread.isNameAvailable(nameObj);
        nameCheckedList.add(nameCheckedObj);
    }

    return nameCheckedList;
}
```

The async method which will do the processing

```
@Async("nameAvailabilityExecutor")
public Name isNameAvailable(Name nameObj) {
    String name = nameObj.getName();

    if (getByNameCheck(name)) {
        nameObj.setAvailable(true);
    } else {
        nameObj.setAvailable(false);
    }

    return nameObj;
}
```

From my understanding CompletableFuture is what I need to use here? What is the correct way using CompletableFuture in this scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply make `isNameAvailable(Name)` return a `CompletableFuture`:

```
@Async("nameAvailabilityExecutor")
public CompletableFuture<Name> isNameAvailable(Name nameObj) {
    String name = nameObj.getName();

    if (getByNameCheck(name)) {
        nameObj.setAvailable(true);
    } else {
        nameObj.setAvailable(false);
    }

    return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(nameObj);
}
```

Spring `@Async` will deal with the asynchronous execution as you intended.

You will also need to change the return type of `isNameAvailable(LinkedHashSet)` to a simple `List` or something similar, since it does not really make sense to store `CompletableFuture`s in a `Set`:

```
public List<CompletableFuture<Name>> isNameAvailable(LinkedHashSet<Name> nameList) {
    List<CompletableFuture<Name>> nameCheckedList = new ArrayList<>();

    for (Name nameObj : nameList) {
        CompletableFuture<Name> nameCheckedObj = domainAvailabilityServiceThread.isNameAvailable(nameObj);
        nameCheckedList.add(nameCheckedObj);
    }

    return nameCheckedList;
}
```

Note that it is probably not a good idea to asynchronously modify the state of an object like you are doing here with `Name`, as it makes it more difficult to guarantee what state will be visible to the calling thread. It might be preferable to work with `CompletableFuture<Boolean>`:

```
@Async("nameAvailabilityExecutor")
public CompletableFuture<Boolean> isNameAvailable(Name nameObj) {
    String name = nameObj.getName();

    return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(getByNameCheck(name));
}
```

and return a `Map<Name, CompletableFuture<Boolean>>`:

```
public Map<Name, CompletableFuture<Boolean>> isNameAvailable(LinkedHashSet<Name> nameList) {
    Map<Name, CompletableFuture<Boolean>> nameCheckedList = new HashMap<>();

    for (Name nameObj : nameList) {
        CompletableFuture<Boolean>> nameCheckedObj = domainAvailabilityServiceThread.isNameAvailable(nameObj);
        nameCheckedList.put(nameObj, nameCheckedObj);
    }

    return nameCheckedList;
}
```

and let the calling thread do whatever is needed with that check.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I decided to go with your suggestion and return `Map<Name, CompletableFuture<Boolean>>` The calling method is calling it using this code `Map<Name, CompletableFuture<Boolean>> nameCompletableFutureMap = domainAvailabilityService.isNameAvailable(nameList);` Should I be iterating though the map with a Thread.sleep until CompletableFuture.isDone() returns true? What is the best way to wait for all the CompletableFuture to finish?

Comment: If you really need to wait (block), you can call `join()` on each. If you need to return a future as well, you can use `CompletableFuture.allOf()` to remain asynchronous.